# UITableView: stop auto scrolling beyond selected position

Tags: uitableview, scroll

I have a grouped UITableView which displays a number of cells, which includes both normal (text) cells as well as one with an UIImageView and another with a MKMapView.  The cells are being used conceptually to show the user different parts of an area (such as description etc, in the text cells) as well as the location (MKMapView) and an image of the area (UIImageView).  The whole table of cells spans several screens.

When I scroll the UITableview, it seems to automatically scroll beyond where I stop scrolling or to scroll back the way it came.  I have pagingEnabled = NO.

It is almost as though the UITableView is trying to show parts of the cells if I haven't scrolled far enough (or too far), and is automatically scrolling the view.

Please can someone explain why it is behaving this way and how to make it stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turns out that the behaviour is due to the simulator.  To drag in the sim, you click with the mouse and then move.  I thought I had been dragging, but in actual fact I was scrolling the window by using a two fingered motion on the mac touchpad.  I think this is viewed by the simulator as something other than just a simple scrolling motion.